# How to handle 0E-8 in sql

Tags: sql, hive, rounding, decimalformat

One of my column was havng value 0.0000000 it seems and it turns 0E-8 when am extracting data.ow to handle this.I have tried below commands in hive.

```
round(column,8) as amount
cast(column as decimal(10,8)) as amount
```

The above 2 doesnt working as expected

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: @jarlh showing as Decimal(31,8)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can handle very small numbers such as 0E-8 by using the ROUND function. For example, you can use the following query to round 0E-8 to the nearest hundredth:

SELECT ROUND(0E-8, 2)

This will return 0.00.

You can also use the FORMAT function to format the number as a string with a specific number of decimal places. For example, the following query will format 0E-8 with two decimal places:

SELECT FORMAT(0E-8, '0.00')

This will return '0.00'.

If you want to store very small numbers in a database, you may need to use a data type that supports a larger range of values, such as FLOAT or DOUBLE PRECISION.

Comment: I need to handle in columns....It seems you directly handled in column value